# Google Maps Android bottom sheet extends below the screen bottom bounds

Tags: android, modal-dialog, bottom-sheet

I would like to achieve Bottom Sheet dialog behavior like in Google Maps transport route itinerary: if you click on expandable item the top of the sheet is not moving but the sheet grows below the screen bottom bounds. The text on top of the sheet is fixed but the dialog itself increases in height.
How to achieve this behavior with `BottomSheetDialogFragment`?

Comment: No, this one: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r0y1u1KkGpEHTUYMCOOShnHpyGaNAGJq

Comment: So you don't want to hide map?

Comment: It is more about the behavior of the dialog. When i expand a collapsed item inside it, it does not increase its height upwards, but it "grows" downwards..This is not a out of the box behavior of the BottomSheetDialog

Comment: Might be your parent layout have layout_gravity="bottom"

Comment: You want this type : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LapqSZDg_td-5Q9TLnr7vts5Ugly0LOo/view?usp=sharing